# Can I do packet sniffing out of the box on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, networking, sniffing

I'm doing some development, a Java app that communicates via HTTP. The log4j isn't helping me much so I'd like to see the actual HTTP Request that I am creating once it gets sent out.

I know that in the Windows world I use a packet sniffer for this. Sometimes I'm surprised by what OS X can do out of the box - can it do this?

If not, what's a good packet sniffer on OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out that [tcpdump](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA21467) is an easy way to do it out of the box.

Comment: you probably need to run as root. There are a couple ways to get access. I set my root password.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.wireshark.org/download.html

This is the best one I have used so far. I do not know of anything that is available "right out of the box" though.

Comment: "I do not know of anything that is available "right out of the box"" tcpdump, which ships with the OS.

Answer (score 1):

[HTTPScoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/) does perfectly the job for simple http sniffing.

Although a bit old fashion looking still worth to mention [Eavesdrop](http://www.baurhome.net/software/eavesdrop/) for general basic sniffing