# Mac Wireshark alternatives

Tags: mac, networking, sniffing

Do you know any **good alternatives for wireshark** (network analyzer) running on a **Mac OS X 10.5**+?

Wireshark is not that handy like on an Windows OS (user interface with X11, ...).

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A few options:

- [tcpdump](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3994)
- [Cocoa Packet Analyzer](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/index.php)
- [Packet Peeper](http://packetpeeper.sourceforge.net/)
- [AirMagnet](http://www.airmagnet.com/)

See also [this search on macupdate](http://search.macupdate.com/search.php?keywords=Packet%20Sniffer).

Answer shamelessly cribbed from these other SU questions:

- [Is there a nice, graphical, packet sniffer for Mac OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/76656/is-there-a-nice-graphical-packet-sniffer-for-mac-osx)
- [Can I do packet sniffing out of the box on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/18815/can-i-do-packet-sniffing-out-of-the-box-on-os-x)
- [How can I sniff packets from an unsecured wireless network?](https://superuser.com/questions/27832/how-can-i-sniff-packets-from-an-unsecured-wireless-network)

Comment: I've not used it for some time, but I found Cocoa Packet Analyzer not a good replacement. For example: I never managed to filter outgoing SMTP traffic *including its responses* -- but maybe things have changed.